# Touch behaving weird in Unity 3D Android

Tags: android, touch, unity-game-engine

I have a Car in unity with four 3D texts Accelerate,Brake,Left and Right. All having box colliders. I have attach the following script to Main Camera

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GamePlayCamera : MonoBehaviour {

void FixedUpdate ()
    {
        if ( Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.IPhonePlayer ||
            Application.platform == RuntimePlatform.Android )
        {
            if ( Input.touchCount <= 0 )
                return;

            for(int i = 0 ; i<Input.touches.Length; i++)
            {

                Touch touch  = Input.touches[i];
                if ( touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began )
                {

                    OnTouchBegan( touch.position );
                }
                else if(touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
                {
                    OnTouchEnd( touch.position );
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if ( Input.GetMouseButtonDown( 0 ) )
            {
                Debug.Log(Input.mousePosition);
                OnTouchBegan( Input.mousePosition );
            }
            else if(Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
            {
                OnTouchEnd( Input.mousePosition );
            }
        }
    }

        void OnTouchBegan (Vector2 screenPos)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( screenPos );
            RaycastHit hit;

            if ( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit ) )
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("Acc"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("Accel", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("brk"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchDown", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("LFT"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchDown", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("RHT"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchDown", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }

            }

        }

        void OnTouchEnd (Vector2 screenPos)
        {
            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay( screenPos );
            RaycastHit hit;

            if ( Physics.Raycast( ray, out hit ) )
            {
                if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("Acc"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("DAccel", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("brk"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchUp", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("LFT"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchUp", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }
                else if(hit.collider.gameObject.name.Equals("RHT"))
                {
                    hit.collider.gameObject.SendMessage("TouchUp", SendMessageOptions.DontRequireReceiver);
                }

            }

        }
```

}

The logic of car movement is fine I have tested it multiple times using mouse.
The problem is that multi touch is not working properly. First time MultiTouch works but after clicking the buttons couple of time it starts behaving weird. When I click left the functionality of Accelerate starts working and some time nothing happens. Can any one tell me what the issue is? I am new to Unity and having some problems. Please help.
Thanks.

Comment: hi, nice to meet you again, I see that you accepted my answer, just for your information, that solution is only for simple usage, if you want to implement a car game controller, I suggest you to buy some plugins, such as NGUI(http://www.tasharen.com/?page_id=140) and Finger Gesture. NGUI is highly recommendated, you can see its source code and learn every thing about your question.

Comment: Hi, but as you know I am new to Unity I want to learn it first then I will buy the plugins to save time. What do you think is my approach right? Plugins will work when I will complete the game for learning purposes I am using 3D texts.